# Plugin de Kotlin para Android Studio 4.0.1 no esta localizable "kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.72.pom"

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

He intentado compilar un proyecto en Android Studio 4.0.1 con Kotlin y me lanza el siguiente error:

```
Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.72.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.72/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.72.pom
If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
Required by:
    project :
```

al abrir el navegador y pegar esta URL me notifica que el plugin no ha sido encontrado mostrandome el error 404 de google

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Verifica que tu archivo build.gradle a nivel de proyecto tenga los repositorios de google y jcenter tanto en buildscript como en allprojects

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.72"
    repositories {
        //Aqui
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        //Aqui también
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

También te sugiero actualizar tu plugin de kotlin a la versión más reciente hasta la fecha

```
ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.21"
```

Espero que te sirva